# Dell Latitude D610

Tags: laptop

I have 2 Dell Latitudes with an identical problem. Units work fine when charger is in use. When unplugged, there is a white "smear" starting at the lower left corner and progressing to the center of the screen. The Windows logo and some desktop icons are still visible but resolution is very poor. New factory battery has been installed in both with no difference. When charger is re-attached, screen is restored after about 30 seconds. Both of  these have been updated to Win7 Home Premium from XP.(Genuine software) Any ideas?